# Displaying an array of Strings in a JTextArea

Tags: java, arrays, user-interface

i've been stuck on getting one of my JTextArea's to display an array of Strings that represent letters in a word in a hangman game. Once the user guesses a letter, (assuming it's right), it should reflect into the array. Instead, it seems to be only adding the letter that was guessed, and not the blanks or the rest of the array. I want to set the guessed letter equal to the correct index in the array and then have it shown on the screen. Here is my code:

```
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class GuiClass extends JFrame {

char guess = ' ';
int numGuesses = 0;
char[] letterGuessedAgainst = null;
String wordInPlay = " ";
String[] hangmanScores = null;
ArrayList<Character> wrongGuesses = null;
boolean isGuessSuccessfull = false;

private Container contents;
JRadioButton rbEasy;
JRadioButton rbHard;
ButtonGroup difficultyGroup;
JTextField txtfldWord;
JTextArea txtareaWord;
JLabel difficultyPrompt;
JLabel userDifficulty;
JButton btnStartGame;
JButton btnGuessSubmit;
JButton btnWordGuessSubmit;
JPanel topPanel;
JPanel midPanel;
JLabel topLabel;
JPanel guessPanel;
JPanel letterPanel;
JLabel word;
JTextArea txtareaNumGuesses;
JTextField txtfldGuess;
JTextField txtfldWordGuess;
JTextArea txtareaguessedLetters;
JTextArea txtareaLettersLeft;

public GuiClass(){
    super("Hangman GUI");

    contents = getContentPane();

    //create a new panel & set layout
    midPanel = new JPanel();
    midPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,3));

    //layout manager
    topLabel = new JLabel("Welcome to Hangman!");
    contents.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    //create new ButtonHandlers
    ButtonHandler buttonHandler = new ButtonHandler();
    ButtonHandler2 btnHndlrNewGame = new ButtonHandler2();

    //create difficulty buttons/labels & add ActionListeners
    difficultyPrompt = new JLabel("First, Choose A Difficulty:");

    rbEasy = new JRadioButton("Easy");
    rbHard = new JRadioButton("Hard");
    userDifficulty = new JLabel("Game Difficulty: ");
    difficultyGroup = new ButtonGroup();

    difficultyGroup.add(rbEasy);
    difficultyGroup.add(rbHard);

    rbEasy.addItemListener(buttonHandler);
    rbHard.addItemListener(buttonHandler);

    midPanel.add(topLabel);
    midPanel.add(difficultyPrompt);
    midPanel.add(rbEasy);
    midPanel.add(rbHard);
    midPanel.add(userDifficulty);

    topPanel = new JPanel();
    JLabel btnStartNewGame = new JLabel("Next, Start a new game!");
    btnStartGame = new JButton("Start A New Game");
    btnStartGame.addActionListener(btnHndlrNewGame);

    topPanel.add(btnStartNewGame);
    topPanel.add(btnStartGame);     

    guessPanel = new JPanel();
    JLabel lblGuess = new JLabel("Guess: ");
    JLabel lblWordGuess = new JLabel("Word Guess: ");

    btnGuessSubmit = new JButton("Submit");
    btnGuessSubmit.addActionListener(btnHndlrNewGame);

    btnWordGuessSubmit = new JButton("Submit");
    btnGuessSubmit.addActionListener(btnHndlrNewGame);

    txtfldGuess = new JTextField(10);
    txtfldWordGuess = new JTextField(10);

    guessPanel.add(lblGuess);
    guessPanel.add(txtfldGuess);
    guessPanel.add(btnGuessSubmit);

    guessPanel.add(lblWordGuess);
    guessPanel.add(txtfldWordGuess);
    guessPanel.add(btnWordGuessSubmit);

    letterPanel = new JPanel();
    JLabel lblGuessedLetters = new JLabel("Guessed Letters:");
    JLabel lblLettersInWord = new JLabel("Letters Left:");
    JLabel lblNumGuesses = new JLabel("Guess Number: ");

    txtareaNumGuesses = new JTextArea(5,5);
    txtareaNumGuesses.setEditable(false);

    txtareaguessedLetters = new JTextArea(5,15);
    txtareaguessedLetters.setEditable(false);

    txtareaLettersLeft = new JTextArea(5,15);
    txtareaLettersLeft.setEditable(false);

    letterPanel.add(lblGuessedLetters);
    letterPanel.add(txtareaguessedLetters);
    letterPanel.add(lblLettersInWord);
    letterPanel.add(txtareaLettersLeft);
    letterPanel.add(lblNumGuesses);
    letterPanel.add(txtareaNumGuesses);

    JPanel wordPanel = new JPanel();
    word = new JLabel("Word is: ");
    //txtfldWord = new JTextField(10);
    txtareaWord = new JTextArea(20,20);
    //txtfldWord.setEditable(false);
    txtareaWord.setEditable(false);
    wordPanel.add(word);
    //wordPanel.add(txtfldWord);
    wordPanel.add(txtareaWord);

    //add contents of panels to the container
    contents.add(midPanel);
    contents.add(topPanel);
    contents.add(guessPanel);
    contents.add(letterPanel);
    contents.add(wordPanel);

    setSize(800,600);
    setVisible(true);
}//end constructor

private class ButtonHandler implements ItemListener{
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent ie){
        if (ie.getSource()==rbEasy){
            userDifficulty.setText("Game Difficulty: Easy");
        }//end if

        if (ie.getSource()==rbHard){
            userDifficulty.setText("Game Difficulty: Hard");
        }//end if

    }//end method
}//end ButtonHandler inner class

private class ButtonHandler2 implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
        if (ae.getSource()==btnStartGame){
            if (rbEasy.isSelected()){
                ArrayList<String> easyHmWords = new ArrayList<String>();
                String filename = "easyhangmanwords.txt";
                BufferedReader infile = null;
                try {
                    infile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
                }//end try
                catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.getMessage();
                }//end catch

                String re = "";
                try {
                    while ((re=infile.readLine())!=null){ // reading one line
                        easyHmWords.add(re);
                    }//end while
                    System.out.println("words in file: "+easyHmWords);
                }//end try
                catch (IOException e) {
                    e.getMessage();
                }//end while
                try {
                    infile.close();
                }//end try
                catch (IOException e) {
                    e.getMessage();
                }//end catch

                wordInPlay = "";
                int randomNumber = 0;
                Random rand = new Random();
                int maxRandomNumber = 0;

                word.setText("Word is: Set");
                //System.out.println("Okay, the word is set!");
                maxRandomNumber = easyHmWords.size();
                System.out.println("Size of arraylist: "+easyHmWords.size());
                randomNumber = rand.nextInt(maxRandomNumber);
                System.out.println("random num: "+randomNumber);
                wordInPlay = easyHmWords.get(randomNumber);
                System.out.println("word in play: "+wordInPlay);

                //figures out how many letters the word has
                int lettersInWord = wordInPlay.length();
                System.out.println("Letters in word: "+lettersInWord);

                //creates an array of hangman scores which is the size of the letters in the word
                hangmanScores = new String[lettersInWord];

                //for loop to iterate through the array and assign "_" to the spaces
                for (int i = 0; i < hangmanScores.length; i++) {
                    hangmanScores[i] = " _ ";
                }//end for

                for (int i = 0; i < hangmanScores.length; i++){
                    //txtareaWord.setText(hangmanScores[i]);
                    //txtfldWord.append(hangmanScores[i]);
                    txtareaWord.append((hangmanScores[i]));
                }//end for

            }//end if
        }//end if

        if(btnGuessSubmit == ae.getSource()){ //getting problems in this if statement
            guess = txtfldGuess.getText().charAt(0);
            letterGuessedAgainst = wordInPlay.toCharArray();

            for (int i = 0; i < letterGuessedAgainst.length; i++) {//goes through the letters of the word in play
                ***if(letterGuessedAgainst[i]==guess){//if a letter matches up,
                    hangmanScores[i] = Character.toString(guess);
                    isGuessSuccessfull = true;
                }//end if
            }//end for

            for (int k =0; k < hangmanScores.length; k++){//displays the ______ in the text area
                txtareaWord.setText((hangmanScores[k]));***

                System.out.print(hangmanScores[k]);//testing purposes
            }//end for

            numGuesses++;
            txtareaNumGuesses.setText(" "+numGuesses);

        }//end for
        if(isGuessSuccessfull = false){
            wrongGuesses.add(guess);
            txtareaguessedLetters.append(wrongGuesses+"");

        }//end if
    }//end method
}//end private inner class

public static void main (String[] args){
    GuiClass estGUI = new GuiClass();
    estGUI.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}//end main method
}//end class
```

this is the part of the code that doesn't display the correct parts of the array:

```
                ***if(letterGuessedAgainst[i]==guess){//if a letter matches up,
                    hangmanScores[i] = Character.toString(guess);
                    isGuessSuccessfull = true;
                }//end if
            }//end for

            for (int k =0; k < hangmanScores.length; k++){
                txtareaWord.setText((hangmanScores[k]));***
```

Comment: try debugging it and/or posting the relevant code that you are having trouble with.

Comment: Try using `setText` instead of `append`

Comment: when i do that the area displays this: (given a guessed letter) _  _  _  _  _  _  _ h _  _  _  _  _  _ h _  _  _  _  _  _

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you are calling `setText` every time you want to add a new character to the `JTextArea` in question, this is, first, clearing any existing text and then adding the new `String`, which, in this case, is the last thing you entered.

There are a few ways you could fix this, but because you want to remove the existing text first and then replace it, it's probably better to build a buffer of what you want and apply it all in a single step...

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(hangmanScores.length);
for (int k = 0; k < hangmanScores.length; k++) {//displays the ______ in the text area
    sb.append(hangmanScores[k]);
    System.out.print(hangmanScores[k]);//testing purposes
}//end for
txtareaWord.setText(sb.toString());
```

You also seem to have attached multiple `ActionListener`s to your button, as each time I clicked it, it counted for two guesses...